# How can I search a word of a file in another file in C?

Tags: c

I have 2 files, first one is my main file and another one is ignoreList which contains banned words. I want to scan all words of the main file and search in the ignoreList and print not banned words. By the way, banned words are replaced line by line in the ignoreList. However, there is a problem that it does not print any words, prints only numbers. Here is my code;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int banList(char a[20]);
int main() {

    char word[20];
    FILE *mainFile;

    if ((mainFile = fopen("file1.html", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! File does not exist.");
    }

    while( fscanf(mainFile, "%s", word) != EOF ) {

        if(banList(word) == 1) {

        }
        else {
            printf("%s\n", &word);
        }
    }

    fclose(mainFile);
    return 0;
    }

int banList(char a[20]) {

    char ban[20];
    FILE *ignoreList;

    if ((ignoreList= fopen("file2.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! IgnoreList file does not exist to compare.");
    }

    while( fscanf(ignoreList, "%s", ban) != EOF ) {

        if (strcmp(a,ban)==1) {
            fclose(ignoreList);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(ignoreList);
    return 0;

}
```

MainFile =

```
1 brenckman , ae . scs . an experimental study of a wing in a propeller slipstream was made in order to determine the spanwise distribution of the lift increase due to slipstream at different angles of attack of the wing and at different free stream to slipstream velocity ratios . the results were intended in part as an evaluation ...
```

ignoreList =

```
a
ain't
am
an
and
are
aren't
as
at
be
been
by
...
```

Comment: before return close the file ignorelist

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar I tried, but it didnt work.

Comment: it's just a suggestion not a solution :) dont worry we'll find out

Comment: @bluesshead What is the output you are getting?

Comment: does the ignore file contains only char?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava only dot,comma and numbers

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar yes, it contains only char

Comment: Please show the full code (there are no `#include` library headers) and a small sample of the banned words file and the main file, say 3 lines of each.

Comment: @bluesshead What is in ban? Where are you initializing ban? Please give the content of the file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are printing the address because you didn't specify the pointer when declaring. so it prints address insteadt of data

wrong:

```
printf("%s\n", &word);
```

correct one:

```
 printf("%s\n", word);
```

for strcmp()

> if Return value < 0 then it indicates a is less than ban.
>
> if Return value > 0 then it indicates ban is less than a.
>
> if Return value = 0 then it indicates a is equal to ban.

you have

```
if(strcmp(a,ban)==1) //means doen't match
```

use

```
if(strcmp(a,ban)==0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: dont mention it